# How to use robots.txt to disallow to some controller in Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, seo, robots.txt

I'm quite new to the topic robots.txt. I had look about it for few hours and tried tom implement it. I have controller named login and view. All I want is Google search to list my view controller only not the login controller. But now when I search for my site in Google, it is showing login before the view. How can I remove login from listed in Goolge using robots.txt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of information about robots.txt You can find there:
http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

Simple example:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /test/
```

With this code, all user agents are disallowed to index "/test/" address. Read about robots txt or show us Your code.